# Bash script works in while but not in until?

Tags: bash

This is very simple. I run this as a systemctl.

```
#!/bin/bash


until ping -c1 $1 www.google.com &>/dev/null
        do protonvpn c -f
done
```

my systemctl is:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          protonvpn
# Required-Start:    $all
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: autostartvpn
### END INIT INFO

[Unit]
After=remote-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/dir/startupscript

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It does not work (the upper script) when i execute it as systemctl, and it stops working generally after reboot for unknown reason.

I want to run this command `protonvpn c -f` on boot as soon as i get internet connection and i want it to loop until a connection is found (then kill-switch controls the app, and all works indefinitely).

Can you help  me make it work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a service after having an active network connection, you can use this on your Systemd service file:

```
After=network-online.target
```

I think that would kill two birds with one stone, because that behaviour implies that you no longer should need to add any kind of check in your script to make sure it runs after network connection is established.

Answer (score 0):

[@hads0m has the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61978858/96588), but the loop pattern is also wrong.

```
until command1
do
    command2
done
```

does not do what you think. If `command1` succeeds the first time then it *never* runs `command2`. If `command1` does *not* succeed it'll run `command2`, and if that command runs in the background or exits it'll run `command1` again. What you want instead is

```
until command1
do
    sleep 1
done
command2
```

to not run a busy loop and to only run `command2` when the prerequisite is met.